# Get and remove <defs> elements from <svg> with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Is there a way to remove `<defs>` elements from `<svg>` with plain javascript or jquery?

I found solutions with d3 library, but I would like to avoid adding the whole library just for this.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/remove/ / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: `document.querySelector("defs").remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove elements using [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) and passing the desired selector to querySelector

```js
document.querySelector("defs").remove();
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!-- Some graphical objects to use -->
  <defs>
    <circle id="myCircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="5" />

    <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="gold" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="red" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <!-- using my graphical objects -->
  <use x="5" y="5" xlink:href="#myCircle" fill="url('#myGradient')" />
</svg>
```

For multiple elements use querySelectorAll and NodeList.forEach:

```
document.querySelectorAll("defs").forEach(EL => EL.remove());
```